While applying border radius to HTML table row, additional background can be seen
I am using an HTML table where I am applying color to the table cells. The table cells have border-radius properties.
But, an additional background can be seen after the border-radius is applied. Here is the image

How to remove this
My code is following
        .attendance-table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0 10px;

            thead tr {
                height: 25px;
            }

            thead tr th {
                padding: 0 5px;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            tbody tr {
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
                overflow: hidden;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            tbody tr td {
                height: 30px;
                padding: 6px 15px;
                border: none;
            }

            tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
                background-color: rgba(34,158,219,0.1);
            }

            tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            }

            tbody tr td:first-child {
                border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
            }

            tbody tr td:last-child {
                border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
            }
        }


Please add enough (relevant) code to create a [mre]

Using your code I do not get this effect when applying it to a table. Is there maybe another element behind the table or in other words, is the table inside of another element with background-color?

From the initial questions it does not get clear what is the final goal but I can see the main mistake.
You are trying to apply border radius to a different element to what gets the shadow. (td has border radius and tr has the shadow) This means that you are trying to apply background and a shadow to elements with different shape.
The easiest solution to the given css code is to add border radius to the table row as well:
sth like:
tbody tr {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    border-radius: 5px
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

there might be more sophisticated solutions but we need more details on what is  expected and what the html looks like.

Solved it! I had to add border-radius to this part
tbody tr {box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);overflow: hidden;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;border-radius: 5px;}

Without an example (HTML-code) I could only guess.
You could try to pase "background-color: #0000;" at the ".attendance-table", for example:


 .attendance-table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0 10px;
            background-color: #0000;



If this does not work please paste us an HTML-example of how you use your stylesheet.
